# gunicorn not installing on heroku when using Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to run a simple photo portfolio website on heroku, written in Flask with photo information stored in a postgresql database, accessed using Flask-SQLAlchemy. Everything runs perfectly on my local machine, and I've created a heroku app and can git push to it with no issues.
My Procfile contains `web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-` as per the official heroku tutorial for using Flask.
In my requirements.txt file, I've included `gunicorn==19.2.1`

When I run `git push heroku master`, my code is uploaded with no issue. All the dependencies are installed fine, and but the dyno crashes immediately upon starting up. Here's the log:

```
2015-02-17T03:50:12.108340+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 54f0d35 by email@gmail.com
2015-02-17T03:50:12.108340+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v15 created by email@gmail.com
2015-02-17T03:50:12.271089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-17T03:50:15.398170+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-17T03:50:16.433659+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-17T03:50:17.209823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-17T03:50:17.226212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've tried everything I can think of. Restarting the app does no good, nor does removing the gunicorn version specification in requirements.txt.
Another stackoverflow thread recommended forcing a gunicorn install with `heroku run pip install gunicorn`, which produces a message saying gunicorn has been successfully installed, yet if I immediately run `heroku run gunicorn`, I'm met with another `gunicorn: command not found`

Anything I'm missing? Thanks in advance.
requirements.txt contains:

```
Cython==0.20.2
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Jinja2==2.7.3
Mako==1.0.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pygments==1.6
SQLAlchemy==0.9.8
Sphinx==1.2.2
Twisted==13.2.0
Werkzeug==0.10.1
alembic==0.7.4
altgraph==0.10.2
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
certifi==14.05.14
docutils==0.12
flask-heroku==0.1.9
gunicorn==19.2.1
itsdangerous==0.24
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
mock==1.0.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
nose==1.3.3
numpy==1.8.0rc1
pandas==0.14.1
psycopg2==2.6
py2app==0.7.3
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyenchant==1.6.6
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013.7
scipy==0.13.0b1
six==1.4.1
sympy==0.7.5
tornado==4.0.1
virtualenv==12.0.7
wsgiref==0.1.2
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

Comment: Are you sure your other decencies are being installed? What is the content of your requirements.txt and what is the output of `heroku run pip list`?

Comment: Ah, so I think @dirn might be on to something – pip install doesn't appear to be doing anything at all, despite messages to the contrary. 'heroku run pip list' produces `Running 'pip list' attached to terminal... up, run.8492

pip (6.0.6)

setuptools (11.3.1)`

Comment: Do you have a setup.py file?

Comment: I don't have a setup.py file because I shouldn't need to install anything from my local machine, everything should be available via a package manager. It's just weird that though pip says that it's installing things, nothing is actually installed. Any thoughts?

Comment: You still haven't shown us what's in your requirements.txt.

Comment: I added the contents of requirements.txt to my original post since it wouldn't fit in the comments. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you really use all those libraries? It looks like you ran `pip freeze` on your Mac's site-packages.